# How to use std::bind function as a signal handler in C++?

Tags: c++, signals, stdbind

I am using the following code to add signal handling to my C++ classes:

```
namespace {
    std::atomic<bool> signal_flag(false);   
}
void terminate_or_interrupt_handler(int signal) {
    switch (signal) {
        case SIGTERM:
            WARN("SIGTERM received");
            signal_flag.store(true);
            break;
        case SIGINT:
            WARN("SIGINT received");
            signal_flag.store(true);
            break;
        default:
            throw (std::runtime_error("Unhandled signal received"));
    }
}
signal(SIGTERM, &terminate_or_interrupt_handler);
```

This code works, but it requires the signal handler function to be define in the same scope as the signal flag variable. I decided to modify the code and pass the `signal_flag` by reference to the function and use `std::bind` to "specialize" the handler to my class.

```
 void terminate_or_interrupt_handler(std::atomic<bool>& signal_flag, int signal) {
    switch (signal) {
        case SIGTERM:
            WARN("SIGTERM received");
            signal_flag.store(true);
            break;
        case SIGINT:
            WARN("SIGINT received");
            signal_flag.store(true);
            break;
        default:
            throw (std::runtime_error("Unhandled signal received"));
    }
}
auto my_handler = std::bind(terminate_or_interrupt_handler, std::ref(my_class_signal_flag), std::placeholders::_1);
signal(SIGTERM, &my_handler);
```

However, I get this compile error:

```
error: cannot convert ‘std::_Bind<void (*(std::reference_wrapper<std::atomic<bool> >, std::_Placeholder<1>))(std::atomic<bool>&, int)>*’ to ‘__sighandler_t’ {aka ‘void (*)(int)’}
```

Is there a way to use a bound function in conjunction with the `signal` function in C++?

Comment: Is the last line of your last-but-one code box right? I suspect you should have written `my_handler` instead of `terminate_or_interrupt_handler`

Comment: my_class_signal_flag is the variable defined in another class that I am trying to bind it to the general signal handler.

Comment: There are many things you can't do in a signal handler, and throwing exceptions is one of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result of `std::bind` is an unspecified function object whose type cannot be converted into `void (*)(int)`. Try encapsulating it:

```
void handler_foo(int signal)
{
    return terminate_or_interrupt_handler(signal_flag, signal);
}
```

Or, if C++11 is available, a lambda might be better:

```
signal(SIGTERM, [](int signal) { return terminate_or_interrupt_handler(signal_flag, signal); });
```

Note that since `signal_flag` is a global variable (namespace-scope variable), no capture is required. A non-capturing lambda can be implicitly converted into the corresponding function pointer type.

Answer (score 2):

If your software runs under Linux and your process does a `poll()` or a `select()` it may be a lot cleaner to use `signalfd()`.

I've implemented such in my [eventdispatcher](https://github.com/m2osw/eventdispatcher), the [ed::signal](https://github.com/m2osw/eventdispatcher/blob/master/eventdispatcher/signal.cpp) class¹. Here is a copy of the constructor:

```
snap_communicator::snap_signal::snap_signal(int posix_signal)
    : f_signal(posix_signal)
    //, f_socket(-1) -- auto-init
    //, f_signal_info() -- auto-init
    //, f_unblock(false) -- auto-init
{
    int const r(sigismember(&g_signal_handlers, f_signal));
    if(r != 0)
    {
        if(r == 1)
        {
            // this could be fixed, but probably not worth the trouble...
            throw snap_communicator_initialization_error("the same signal cannot be created more than once in your entire process.");
        }
        // f_signal is not considered valid by this OS
        throw snap_communicator_initialization_error("posix_signal (f_signal) is not a valid/recognized signal number.");
    }

    // create a mask for that signal
    //
    sigset_t set;
    sigemptyset(&set);
    sigaddset(&set, f_signal); // ignore error, we already know f_signal is valid

    // first we block the signal
    //
    if(sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &set, nullptr) != 0)
    {
        throw snap_communicator_runtime_error("sigprocmask() failed to block signal.");
    }

    // second we create a "socket" for the signal (really it is a file
    // descriptor manager by the kernel)
    //
    f_socket = signalfd(-1, &set, SFD_NONBLOCK | SFD_CLOEXEC);
    if(f_socket == -1)
    {
        int const e(errno);
        SNAP_LOG_ERROR("signalfd() failed to create a signal listener for signal ")(f_signal)(" (errno: ")(e)(" -- ")(strerror(e))(")");
        throw snap_communicator_runtime_error("signalfd() failed to create a signal listener.");
    }

    // mark this signal as in use
    //
    sigaddset(&g_signal_handlers, f_signal); // ignore error, we already know f_signal is valid
}
```

With that *socket* you can do a `poll()` and it triggers an equivalent to a read event when a signal arrives.

You retrieve the signal information like this:

```
int const r(read(f_socket, &f_signal_info, sizeof(f_signal_info)));
```

with `f_signal_info` being declared as:

```
struct signalfd_siginfo     f_signal_info;
```

The great thing is that now all of that happens in my classes and I don't have any *weird* signal handlers which can get my thread locked up, does not handle C++ exceptions correctly, and other potential problems. On my end, I have C++ classes with virtual functions that get called whenever an event occurs, including Unix signals such as `SIGINT`, `SIGPIPE`, `SIGCHLD`... You could also implement callbacks using boost signals which give you the power of using `std::bind()`.

All of that said, I still use `signal()` for `SIGSEGV`, `SIGBUS`, etc. those that I'm not going to do any extra work when they occur. I try to log the stack trace on those and that's it. So I don't use `signalfd()` on them (see my [ed::signal_handler](https://github.com/m2osw/eventdispatcher/blob/master/eventdispatcher/signal_handler.cpp) implementation).

---

¹ *The old implementation was part of the [snap_communicator](https://github.com/m2osw/snapwebsites/blob/master/libsnapwebsites/src/snapwebsites/snap_communicator.cpp#L2789) environment and the signal class was around line 2789 at time of writing.*